# com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 error after implementing implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'

Tags: android

I got this problem after I added firebase dependencies into gradle:

[image]

Comment: please write error in text, dont use image capture to show error...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this line above your error line :- `//noinspection GradleCompatible` your error will be gone. If after doing this may be your error will not go just migrate your project in androidx and your error will be gone. Follow this step to migrate your project:- Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Firebase Release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019):

> **This release is a MAJOR version update and includes breaking changes.**
>
> With this release, **libraries are migrated from the Android Support Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.**
>
> The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:
>
> - Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
> - Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
> - **Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).**

You're using Support Library, namely, the old `appcompat-v7:28.0.0`. You need to [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to use Firebase Database 18.0.0.